# fftw library, what is the output size of fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d?

Tags: fft, fftw

Im new to fftw library. I have an array of n real data and use fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d to find fft spectrum. What would be the size of the output. Is it n as same as the input? Also, is the result center around 0 Hz or I have to manually do it?

Answer (score 3):

For a real-to-complex transform you get N / 2 + 1 complex outputs for N real inputs (the redundant symmetric outputs are not generated).

The 0 Hz component is in bin 0.

This is all covered in the [FFTW manual](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question, but I hope it can be a solution to your problem.

---

If you only want to find the spectrum of your data , you might use the "halfcomplex" format.

Here is an piece of code:

```
double *in,*out;
fftw_plan myplan;
in  = fftw_malloc (N*sizeof(double));
out = fftw_malloc (N*sizeof(double));

myplan = fftw_plan_r2r_1d(N,in,out,FFTW_R2HC,FFTW_FORWARD);

// Fill in[] with your data.
...
fftw_execute(myplan);
```

Now `out` contains r0, r1, r2, ..., rn/2, i(n+1)/2-1, ..., i2, i1 , as it is written in the manual.

- r0 ,`out[0]`,is the mean value of your data/signal.
- r1 ,`out[1]`,is the real part of the first element of the DFT.
- ...
- i0 is 0 because you're using real data , so it isn't stored in `out`.
- i1 ,`out[N-1]`,is the imaginary part of the first element of the DFT.
- i2 ,`out[N-2]`,is the imaginary part of the second element of the DFT.

If N is a even number , then r(N/2) `out[N/2]` is the Nyquist frequency amplitude.

> Im new to fftw library

Remember that FFTW computes only the product of your data by the trigonometric functions, but it don't normalize them.
You can find more info about the halfcomplex [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real_002dto_002dReal-Transform-Kinds.html#Real_002dto_002dReal-Transform-Kinds).